# A doubt on Christoffel symbols: to be a tensor, or not to be, what's the answer to that question?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, coordinate-systems

Following $[1]$ we realize that, in order to construct a covariant derivative, we must to compare two possible covariant derivatives such as: $(\bar{\nabla}_{a} - \nabla_{a})\Omega_{b}$, where $\Omega_{b}$ is a covector field. Now, the difference of the covariant derivatives defines a tensor field called $C^{c}_{ab}$ which later will be the christoffel symbols.

The Christoffel symbols appears when we identify the bar-covariant derivative as the partial derivative operators:

$$(\bar{\nabla}_{a} - \nabla_{a})\Omega_{b} = C^{c}_{ab}\Omega_{c} \iff  \nabla_{a}\Omega_{b} = \bar{\nabla}_{a}\Omega_{b} -  C^{c}_{ab}\Omega_{c} \implies   $$

$$ (\partial_{a} - \nabla_{a})\Omega_{b} = \Gamma^{c}_{ab}\Omega_{c} \iff  \nabla_{a}\Omega_{b} = \partial_{a}\Omega_{b} -  \Gamma^{c}_{ab}\Omega_{c} \tag{1}$$

But, these indices aren't summation convention, rather, they are the "Penrose's abstract index notation"; therefore these equations are coordinate free (latin indexes represent abstract notation and greek indexes are coordinate-chart representation/summation convention).

There's a convincent explanation for why the gammas are tensors (more generally the $C's$)$[1]$. Wald says then that the components of $\Gamma^{c}_{ab}$, the $\Gamma^{\delta}_{\mu \nu}$, transforms like a tensor but just for a covariant derivative with respect to $\partial_{a}$. But if we change coordinates, and therefore the basis vectors $\partial_{a} \to \partial '_{a}$, then we also need to change the notion of $(1)$ to *another* covariant derivative:

$$\nabla_{a}\Omega_{b} = \partial '_{a} -  \bar{\Gamma}^{c}_{ab}\Omega_{c} \tag{2}$$

and due to this we realize that the components of Christoffell symbols become non-tensorial. Ok, this is convincing, but the fact is, fixing a derivative $\bar{\nabla} _{a}$ in one chart (and following Wald's explanation), the components of $\Gamma^{c}_{ab}$ are indeed components of a tensor because the diference of covariant derivatives gives rise to a tensor in $(1)$. Therefore, due to tensor theory, you should be able to conclude that they transform like a tensor! This is quite confusing.

My doubt is: Christoffel symbols are tensors such as:

$$ \Gamma =\Gamma^{c}_{ab}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{c}}\otimes dx^{a} \otimes dx^{b}?$$

$$* * *$$

$[1]$ WALD.R. *General Relativity*. pages $30-34$.

Comment: Have you read what [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christoffel_symbols) has to say about this?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/445958/

Comment: Christoffel symbols are *not* tensors.  Only their differences are tensors.